# Elf representation in HEX

Tags: embedded, hex, microcontroller, elf, hexdump

I am working on understanding some ground concepts in embedded Systems. My question is similar to [understand hexedit of an elf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179989/understand-hexedit-of-an-elf) . 
In order to burn compiler output to ROM, the .out file is converted to HEX (say intel-hex). I wonder how the following informations are preserved in HEX format:

1. Section header
2. Symbol tables, debug symbols, linker symbols etc.
3. Elf header.
4. If these are preserved in HEX file, how they can be read from hex file?
5. A bit out question but how the microcontroller on boot knows where .data .bss etc. exists in HEX and to be coppied to RAM?

Comment: You're mixing up two very different things.  The 'hexedit of an ELF' would just be the binary contents of the ELF file rendered as hexadecimal bytes for human viewing. But an Intel Hex file is typically a representation of what goes into a programmable memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of that is preserved. A HEX file only contains the raw program and data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

The microcontroller does not know where .data and .bss are located - it doesn't even know that they exist. The start-up code which is executed before `main()` is called contains the start addresses of those sections - the addresses are hard-coded into the program. This start-up code will be in the HEX file like everything else.

Comment: You mean the starup code that is hiddenly linked or the starup code that is included in project (e.g. keil)? In visible starup code there is no such memcpy instruction etc?? Also kindly any related reference link will be highly appreciated. Kind regards

Comment: @Aimal I don't know what you mean with "hidden" vs "visible" startup code. This code is highly system-specific but usually it is provided as open source by the compiler, either written in asm or C. If you single-step through your program with a debugger, from power-on-reset and onward, you'll see this code.

Comment: By visible code i mean this one. https://github.com/hexanaft/stm32f4-discovery-keil-freertos-blink/blob/master/startup/startup_stm32f4xx.s

Comment: Now here there is no memcpy etc instruction.

Comment: @Aimal You'll have to ask your compiler vendor where in their icky start-up code it can be found. Indeed it seems there is no bss or data setup in the linked code. This is rather common, many compilers skip initialization those segments as a "minimal startup" option. However, by skipping this initialization, the program will no longer conform to the C standard. Did you step through your program and see which code that's actually executed?

Comment: Well to be honest it never reaches main when i single step code and the code breaks. It means keil doeznt provide source code that debugger can link via debug symbols rather its binary code (like crt0)!! That is what i was refering as hidden bootstrap code.

Comment: @Lundin  to be fair, I think the keil icky startup code is actually stuffed in there by the compiler or linker automatically, and no explicit .a,.o, or .s is compiled or linked in. (At least in the version I'm using)

Comment: Debuggers are often set to run until the start of main() and then break. Still, this is machine code so they can't hide it from you. Force a MCU reset a single step from there.

Comment: @Aimal : Keil is a company not a compiler, providing toolchains for more than one architecture and their IDE can be used with GCC too; so it is not clear.  Certainly Keil's ARM MDK does not "hide" it's startup code, because it is necessary to modify it to suit your target (for external memory and PLL clock configuration for example).  It is perhaps true that the library and static data initialisation in object code, but it is unlikely that is failing rather that your project configuration being incorrect.  The startup is in startup_xxxx.s and system_xxxx.c, where xxxx is your target processor.

Comment: @Aimal :  Note also that if using C++, constructors for global objects run before main(), so errors  in that code or reliance on initialisation not yet performed can also cause failure.

Comment: Dear @Clifford, I totally agree with u, but as Lundin mentioned in his answer that the addresses are hard coded in starup code, so I was asking where they embed these adresses, I dont see any memory copy instruction in starup files(.startup_xxxx.s and system_xxxx.c). Can you please point me to that bootstrap code that copy .data/.bss etc at startup?

Comment: @Aimal You can probably reverse-engineer the raw machine code, look for branch instructions. The first loop you encounter is likely the .data/.bss copy-down one.

Comment: @ Aimal :  The memory copy is part of the static data initialisation which as I conceded is provided as object code rather than source (it is not "hidden"). It may be a problem if you are using external memory and have not configured the memory controller and bus signals correctly in the startup code.   There are two steps in C - zero-initialisation and initialised data copy.  The functions are trivial, the addresses for them at least will appear in the link map and the symbols in the debugger. C++ has an additional step of calling static constructors.

Comment: @Aimal : Note I pointed out some deficiencies in your question - specifically lack of clarity regarding toolchain.  It will be much easier to answer if you were to edit the question to add the missing information.  For example for ARMCC (the default compiler for Keil ARM-MDK unless you are using v6) the details are at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0241b/index.html

Comment: @Clifford, I applogize for not mentioning any specific toolchain. Actually my intentions were to generally query how exactly the micrcontroller knows which portion of memory (.data etc.) need to be loaded in ram. The link you shared is indeed very helpful.

Comment: @Aimal : But the answer is that it does not know; it just executes instructions; the addresses those instructions act on are determined by the linker.  The minimal C run-time environment requirement is to set a stack pointer and that is also determined by the linker, and either set in the start-up code (_by instructions_), or in the case of Cortex-M for example is loaded from the vector table, allowing Cortex-M to run C code directly form reset.

Answer (score 3):

The elements in points 1 to 3 are not included in the raw binary since they serve no purpose in the application; rather they are used by the linker and the debugger on the development host, and are unnecessary for program execution where all you need is the byte values and the address to write them to, which is more or less all the hex file contains (may also contain a start address record).

Systems that have dynamic linking or self-hosted debug capabilities (such as VxWorks for example) use the object file file.

With respect to point 5, the microcontroller does not need to know; the linker uses that information when resolving absolute and relative addresses in the object code.  Once filly resolved (linked), the addresses are embedded in the code directly.  Again where dynamic loading/linking is used the object file meta-data is required and such systems do not normally load a raw hex file or binary.